# Twilio client.notify returns 403

Tags: next.js, twilio

I need to send notifications in my web app (nextjs) when a user sends a message. I followed [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/send-notifications) but it dowsn't work.

I have the following code:

```
export const notifyUser = async (_identity: string, _message: string) => {
  return await client.notify
    .services(config.TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID)
    .notifications.create({ body: _message, identity: [_identity] });
};
```

I call an api `notify-user` and I invoke `notifyUSer(identity, message)`

Identity is the `user_id` I use to generate the token with the following method:

```
export const tokenGenerator = (identity: string) => {
  // Create an access token which we will sign and return to the client
  const token = new AccessToken(
    config.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
    config.TWILIO_API_KEY,
    config.TWILIO_API_SECRET
  );

  // Assign the provided identity or generate a new one
  token.identity = identity || 'unknown';

  if (config.TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID) {
    // Create a "grant" which enables a client to use IPM as a given user,
    // on a given device
    const chatGrant = new ChatGrant({
      serviceSid: config.TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID,
      pushCredentialSid: config.TWILIO_FCM_CREDENTIAL_SID,
    });
    token.addGrant(chatGrant);
  }

  if (config.TWILIO_SYNC_SERVICE_SID) {
    // Point to a particular Sync service, or use the account default to
    // interact directly with Functions.
    const syncGrant = new SyncGrant({
      serviceSid: config.TWILIO_SYNC_SERVICE_SID || 'default',
    });
    token.addGrant(syncGrant);
  }

  // Serialize the token to a JWT string and include it in a JSON response
  return {
    identity: token.identity,
    token: token.toJwt(),
  };
};
```

I expected to get the response that is in the example but I get the following error:
[image]
What do you think I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio Notify is a different service to Twilio Chat, so you are trying to use incorrect credentials to call the API. You are passing a [Chat service sid](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/service-resource), not a [Notify service sid](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/service-resource), and using the chat identity and not the identity of a [Notify binding](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/binding-resource).

If you are trying to send notifications based on chat messages, you should follow this [guide on push notification configuration for chat](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/push-notification-configuration).

If you are trying to [send notifications outside of chat using Twilio Notify, follow this guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/quickstart/sms).

Answer (score 1):

It has something to do with your authentication for notifications. The 403 error is similar to the 401 unauthorized error but the difference is that the 403 error doesn't allow you to re-authenticate and forbids the request. Check through your authentication part.

You can also check the Twilio debugging guide : https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/troubleshooting/debugging-your-application